# WordPress child categories not displaying

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, parent, categories

If trying to get Wordpress to pull through a list of child titles based on the parent but all its pulls through is just one or two titles. Any suggestions?

Code below

```
function get_categories_list() {
    $parent = $child = array();
    foreach (get_the_category(get_the_id()) as $cat) {
        if ($cat->id === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($cat->category_parent === 0) {
            array_push($parent,$cat);
        } else {
            array_push($child,$cat);
        }
    }
    foreach ($parent as $key => $cat) {
        if ($key !== 0) {
            echo "-";
        }
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->category_parent ) .'"> ' . $cat->name . '</a>';
    }
    foreach ($child as $cat) {
        if ($key !== 0) {
            echo "-";
        }       
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->category_parent ) .'"> ' . $cat->name . '</a>';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($child as $cat) {
    if ($key !== 0) {
        echo "-";
    }       
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->category_parent ) .'"> ' . $cat->name . '</a>';
}
```

Should be

```
foreach ($child as $key => $cat) {
    if ($key !== 0) {
        echo "-";
    }       
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->category_parent ) .'"> ' . $cat->name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: I would also assume get_category_link( $cat->category_parent ) should be get_category_link( $cat->ID ) otherwise the links will be very confusing :)

Comment: Sadly no joy. Its odd as it prints one link but then stops